# contract is deployed but am getting error while running the script

Tags: json

> ```
> C:\Users\lifet\artbysam>node script/runScript.js WARNING:
> NODE_ENV value of 'dev' did not match any deployment config file
> names. WARNING: See
> https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config/wiki/Strict-Mode WARNING: No
> configurations found in configuration
> directory:C:\Users\lifet\artbysam\config WARNING: To disable this
> warning set SUPPRESS_NO_CONFIG_WARNING in the environment. request: { 
> method: 'post',   url: undefined,   maxContentLength: 'Infinity',  
> headers: {
>     pinata_api_key: undefined,
>     pinata_secret_api_key: undefined,
>     'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------083050430309925626050978'   },  
> data: FormData {
>     _overheadLength: 146,
>     _valueLength: 0,
>     _valuesToMeasure: [ [ReadStream] ],
>     writable: false,
>     readable: true,
>     dataSize: 0,
>     maxDataSize: 2097152,
>     pauseStreams: true,
>     _released: false,
>     _streams: [
>       '----------------------------083050430309925626050978\r\n' +
>         'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="4.png"\r\n' +
>         'Content-Type: image/png\r\n' +
>         '\r\n',
>       [DelayedStream],
>       [Function: bound ]
>     ],
>     _currentStream: null,
>     _insideLoop: false,
>     _pendingNext: false,
>     _boundary: '--------------------------083050430309925626050978'   } } Error occurred while pinning file to IPFS:  TypeError
> [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "url" argument must be of type string.
> Received undefined
>     at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
>     at validateString (node:internal/validators:119:11)
>     at Url.parse (node:url:169:3)
>     at Object.urlParse [as parse] (node:url:156:13)
>     at dispatchHttpRequest (C:\Users\lifet\artbysam\node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\http.js:118:22)
>     at new Promise ()
>     at httpAdapter (C:\Users\lifet\artbysam\node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\http.js:48:10)
>     at dispatchRequest (C:\Users\lifet\artbysam\node_modules\axios\lib\core\dispatchRequest.js:58:10)
>     at Axios.request (C:\Users\lifet\artbysam\node_modules\axios\lib\core\Axios.js:108:15)
>     at wrap (C:\Users\lifet\artbysam\node_modules\axios\lib\helpers\bind.js:9:15)
> {   code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE' }
> ```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: am new to coding and trying to build own contract as i tested and deployed the contact on test net Ganache its working fine but when turn back to deploy my assets via ipfs am getting this error